# Converting UUIDV4 to decimal on base 16

Tags: javascript, uuid

I don't want to share my primary key in the API, So I used UUID4 to generate unique row id. 
But I need to find that row by using generated uuid which may cause performance issues as it's string and also length is too long.
I tried converting this uuid to decimal on base 16.

```
const uuid = UUIDV4() //57d419d7-8ab9-4edf-9945-f9a1b3602c93
const uuidToInt = parseInt(uuid, 16)
console.log(uuidToInt) //1473518039
```

*By default it is only converting first chunk to decimal*
Is safe to use it this way?
How much possibility is there to loose uniqueness of the row?

Comment: It's only converting the first part of the uuid - up to the "-".   You can't do that with a single "parseInt".

Comment: yes, that I realized, also updated the description.thanks

Comment: maybe we should start with your initial sentence: "I don't want to share my primary key in the API" why not? are these uuids or are they numbers? If they are numeric, do they expose any information, besides being a unique identifier?

Comment: Of course they do. `users/:id/profile`. maybe bad route design. But what if anyone else is trying to get user's data. Maybe Admin. So yeah.

Comment: "maybe bad route design" not at all. "But what if anyone else is trying to get user's data." then he should not get it. The API endpoints should be secured that only people with the right credentials can access them. Security through obscurity is very weak.

Comment: For that I have role based access  in the app. But also I don't want anyone with any role can't just guess and get user's data. That's why I don't want to share the primary key. Any alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried converting this uuid to decimal on base 16.

decimal or hexadecimal. A number can't be both. Besides that, the uuid is already a hexadecimal format.

That's how you can convert it into a decimal value.

```js
var uuid = "57d419d7-8ab9-4edf-9945-f9a1b3602c93";
var hex = "0x" + uuid.replace(/-/g, "");
var decimal = BigInt(hex).toString(); // don't convert this to a number.
var base64 = btoa(hex.slice(2).replace(/../g, v => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v, 16))));

console.log({
  uuid,
  hex,
  decimal,
  base64
});
```

Careful, don't convert the BigInt value to a regular number, JS Numbers can not deal with values that big. They have only 53bits of precision. You'll lose the 75 least significant bits of your uuid.

Edit: added base64.

Comment: "don't convert this to a number." ...again it will be a string, thing will be as same as before. I appreciate your suggestion but I want a number that will be easier to query on. What If try converting only first two parts?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari "...again it will be a string" now what number or string? Converting a uuid to a 64bit floating point value (JS Number) you will loose so much information, there will be 37778931862957161709568 possible uuids per number you generate. That's how much uniqueness you loose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is safe to use it this way?

That depends on your definition of *safe*.

> How much possibility is there to loose uniqueness of the row?

A UUIDv4 has 128 bits, so there are 2<sup>128</sup> theoretical possible combinations.

So that's 18'446'744'073'709'551'616 possible UUIDs.

Taking the first section of an UUID leaves you with 32 bits which gives you 2<sup>32</sup> possible combinations: 4'294'967'296.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uuid = "144b60e1-6860-4c42-a698-5e17e8a4dcca";
var hex = "0x" + uuid.replace(/-/g, "");
var decimal = BigInt(hex).toString(); // don't convert this to a number.
var base64 = btoa(hex.slice(2).replace(/../g, v => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v, 16))));

console.log({
  uuid,
  hex,
  decimal,
  base64
});
```