How to use UUID to seed Mersenne Twister algorithm in Nodejs?
Nodejs provides the following function to generate UUID:
crypto.randomUUID([options])
This package of Nodejs uses number as a seed for Mersenne Twister algorithm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mersenne-twister
How do I use UUID as a seed here when it accepts only a number?
What are my options?

Don't use a UUID? What are you doing and why? You have not clearly described your requirements.

A UUID is 128 bits, JS numbers are 64 bit "double" floats. Hence answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60113724/3001761 use BigInt.

Why do you want to/need to use a UUID as a seed?

The last 12 digits of a uuid are about the right size to use as a seed once converted to a number.  parseInt(myUUID.slice(-12), 16)
